# Background image differing in inspect vs actual mobile

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a background image to position correctly on a mobile view. When I look at the website with inspect (or re-sizing the monitor to be a mobile view), the image shows fine. However, when I view it through a phone, the image, for some reason, seems to be re-sizing to fit the phone width instead.

[image]

```css
#hero{
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/molLHMj.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='hero'>
    </div>
</body>
```

If I remember correctly, setting background size as cover would make it so that if the image is bigger than the screen width, it'll simply be hidden, but this seems to be resizing for some reason.

**Edit:**

Setting background-size to **auto** displays the image like how it looks like in chrome's inspector. This shouldn't be the case, as the wider version displays the full width/height (given that it's auto). I'm really lost on what is going on.

**Edit2**

Looks like only the chrome mobile version displays it that way. The default browser renders the background just like how it looks like in the desktop inspector. Really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the size of the image. It was around 3000 in width. When I resized it to around ~1900, the behavior returned to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The image is resizing because you are telling it to with `height: 100vh;`. Additionally, the image is getting skewed because you are placing a restriction on the `width` with: `max-width: 100%;`.

Setting just `max-width: 100%;` (and removing the `height:100vh`) or removing both lines and just sticking with `background-size:cover` could clear this up.

But, if you want the background to cover the entire viewing area, don't place the background on the `div`. In fact, get rid of the `div` and just apply the background to the `body`.

Also, `background-size:cover` does not cause the image to hide, it causes the image to resize to cover the background available. This results in cropping when the background size is smaller than the image.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)**:

> **cover**
>
> A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't
> get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the
> container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the
> image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

Comment: If I want to keep the div to cover up an entire viewing screen while preventing it to re-size on mobile, how would that be? I'm not quite sure on how I would do that without specifically settings its height to be 100vh. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Iruss If you want the background to cover the entire viewing area, don't place the background on the `div`. In fact, get rid of the `div` and just apply the background to the `body`.

Comment: I was trying to get multiple divs that would fill up an entire screen with a full-sized background image. I'm guessing that there are no other ways of doing  so?

Comment: @Iruss Well, there's always a way to do just about anything, but the question here is, why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get multiple divs with different background images that fill up an entire viewing screen. So I guess it sort of looks like multiple sections of landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal like this:

```css
.hero {
height:100vh;
width:100%;
}

.hero:nth-child(1) {
background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');
background-size:cover;
}
    
.hero:nth-child(2) {
background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/molLHMj.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to give me the same resized background image when viewed on a mobile device.

Comment: See updated answer. I apologize if I don't understand how this isn't working. Let me know what it is doing on mobile.

Comment: The same image seems to show in the question above. The image is being resized to the mobile's width instead of being cropped out.