# Background-image in CSS not right on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, background

I'm very new to HTML/CSS and trying to practice by making some basic sites.

The desktop version of my site looks good, and when I inspect it in Chrome the mobile version looks good, but when I actually use a mobile device, the images aren't stretching to resize for the viewport. By trying to fix it I keep breaking it further, so I'd really appreciate some help.

I tried to search for this problem but the solutions I found told me to use `background-size: cover` which is what I'm already doing. I tried to change the body to `body {width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}` and also [the advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642562/background-image-differing-in-inspect-vs-actual-mobile) about taking out the `height: 90vh` and leaving background cover and width, but that reduced it to the size of the div line, which is too small. I feel that [this solution here with media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464250/solved-image-size-messed-up-when-running-website-on-a-mobile-device) is close but I can't figure it out.

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/holdenmad/hannah_website) and [here is the GitHub page](https://holdenmad.github.io/hannah_website/) where you can view it. Thank you in advance!

Desktop:

[image: Desktop version]

Inspector:

[image: Resonsive version in inspector]

Mobile:

[image: Actual mobile version]

Answer (score 0):

try to put `background-position:center center;`
anyway be careful with a fixed background, it causes huge problems with mobile devices performance